# Night mode to SharedPreferences is only causing errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I theoretically have 2 related questions.

1) I tried to make a night mode for my app. That works so far pretty good. Then I wanted to put the setting the User chooses to SharedPreferences. In my first try, It just didn't work. All I did was getting red and causing errors. After a lot of research on the Internet, I found another idea. Now the app is starting but crashing immediately again. The error has to be in the SharedPreferences because as soon as I delete this part it is working again. I just can't find the error and it doesn't show me a red area or so either.

2) Just to check if my research are right. Is it true that it is not possible anymore to make a time-related Night mode? Means dark at night, light at day? I found out that MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME was supposed to do that but is deprecated and they suggest to use MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY which is kinda something really different.

btw. here is my code if it helps from the Setting:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SettingsActivity";
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(DarkMode);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onItemSelected: " + position);
                handleNightMode(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onNothingSelected: ");
            }
        });

    }

    private void handleNightMode(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Log.e(TAG, "Nothing Selected");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.e(TAG, "FOLLLOW_SYSTEM");
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                getDelegate().applyDayNight();
                break;
            case 2:
                Log.e(TAG, "YES");
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                getDelegate().applyDayNight();
                break;
            case 3:
                Log.e(TAG, "NO");
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                getDelegate().applyDayNight();
                break;
            case 4:
                Log.e(TAG, "AUTO");
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
                getDelegate().applyDayNight();
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "FOLLLOW_SYSTEM");
                break;
        }

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String NightMode = preferences.getString("prefTheme", "NO");
        if (NightMode.equals("YES"))
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        if (NightMode.equals("NO"))
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
        else if (NightMode.equals("AUTO"))
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int currentDayNight;
    private Button settings;
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        settings = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);

        currentDayNight = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();

        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSettings();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
04-16 21:31:59.861 11136-11136/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-16 21:32:00.033 11136-11136/com.goldenegg.darkmode W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-16 21:32:00.086 11136-11136/com.goldenegg.darkmode I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-16 21:32:00.087 11136-11136/com.goldenegg.darkmode I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
04-16 21:32:00.168 11136-11149/com.goldenegg.darkmode I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 523(79KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1007KB/2031KB, paused 6.320ms total 27.683ms
04-16 21:32:00.204 11136-11136/com.goldenegg.darkmode D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
04-16 21:32:00.205 11136-11136/com.goldenegg.darkmode E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.goldenegg.darkmode, PID: 11136
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.goldenegg.darkmode/com.goldenegg.darkmode.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.goldenegg.darkmode.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Thanks for your Help.

have a great day

Comment: can you post the full error logs and format your code in the question. also post scrrenshot if you are unsure

Comment: I am sorry for that mistake. I edited it and hope it works better now

Comment: I see issue in this method, `getDelegate().applyDayNight();` specifically these 2 lines `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`  and also what happens in onRecreate() method called from OnRestart().

Comment: This 2 are just in all the time when I create an activity. I never had to change them. I don't understand what's wrong in that? I tried to recreate the old settings when restart but that didnt work. so I wanted to do the SharedPreferences. I guess I need to put  the protected void onRestart()  method out.

Comment: can you remove those 2 lines, from the method and try again

Comment: I removed this 2 line in the MainActivity but it says now the method: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) needs a super.onCreate call. App won't start anymore.

Comment: no you have removed it in the starting of the method, i am talking about those lines present in the end of the method, remove them from the end of the method keep them in the starting.

Comment: I deleted the whole onRestart method. It is still crashing. it says the reason is: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener but the OnClickListener doesnt have a mistake if I am right. I cant find one. did I do at least the SharedPreferences right?

Comment: can you post the updated code

Comment: I edit the Settings and the MainActivity in the top. Thanks so much for your Help Aniruddha

Comment: well you can thank me when we get it running,

Comment: also cn you post the updated crash logs

Comment: I did. I hope it helps

Comment: I now figured out that the dark Mode works when I delete:         SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

but then it doesn't save it in SharedPreferences. So I did something wrong in the SharedPreferences. But The way I learned to save in SharedPreferences I can only save 1 String in. How do I save this if-Clause in SharedPreferences?